# Creating a 3 d face from 2d

Tags: modeling, animation, sculpting, 2d, draw-mode

I would like to ask for something maybe simple. What would be the best (and easiest :) )way to make the drawing below 3d?

Thank you

[image: face]

Comment: Hi, i think you shoul better define "3D" in this context. You can surely convert the gp trace into curves and give that some thickness.. is that the kind of 3D you are looking for? Can you show an example of whar kind of result you are expecting from this input?

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I was thinking maybe this can be put to a uv sphere and somehow gain some curves and form. for example the head would like a ball and the nose will stick out of it. I was thinking a ball and the drawing will be ana anaglyph upon the ball with different heights for each part (nose for example will have bigger height. but as i said i am not an expert on modelling so i was asking maybe you can give some advice of how this can be made as a 3d in a more appealing way